# Is it possible to put Mathjax symbols in bold?

Tags: support, mathjax, typesetting

In Michael Spivak's *Calculus*, he manages to typeset the mathematical symbols so that they appear in bold:

[image: Spivak]

Is there a way of emulating this in Mathjax? Simply enclosing text in bold doesn't work:

> The function **$f$ approaches the limit $l$ near $a$** means: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

The obvious choice of using `\bf` is unsatisfying because the symbols then appear upright:

> The function **$\bf{f}$ approaches the limit $\bf{l}$ near $\bf{a}$** means: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

I also tried using `\boldsymbol`, but this makes everything look weird:

> The function **$\boldsymbol{f}$ approaches the limit $\boldsymbol{l}$ near $\boldsymbol{a}$** means: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

Are there any alternatives available?

Comment: You can use \pmb command; for example $\pmb{f}$.

Comment: The `\mathbf` (math bold font: $\mathbf{abcdefg}$) `\pmb` ($\pmb{abcdefg}$) commands are discussed in the MathJax tutorial---see point 9 (**Fonts**).  Other bold math fonts exist, and are mentioned there, as well.

Comment: That being said, I prefer "**$f$ approaches the limit $\ell$ near $a$**", as the symbols $f$ and $\pmb{f}$ are often understood to represent different objects.  For example, $v$ a variable versus $\pmb{v}$ a vector.

Comment: `\boldsymbol` gives better appearance than `\pmb` in MathJax: $\boldsymbol{abcxyz}$ vs. $\pmb{abcxyz}$.

Comment: These sorts of questions are probably more suited to TeX.SE.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: I'm not sure if Tex.SE accepts questions about Mathjax as opposed to Latex.

Comment: @Joe That's true, although there are often many similarities between LaTeX and Mathjax.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: Indeed, and I would have asked on Tex.Se, but I believe in this particular case there are far fewer options. In Latex I believe there are many packages that you can use that takes care of these problems smoothly.